# invoke restful api in node.js

Tags: node.js, rest

I have a method in my routes and I want to invoke the API mentioned in the uri. I am able to invoke the method successfully.But now I have created a method sample in my restful API in which I need to pass a value from node.js and print the concatenated value.

I have the sample method which accepts a String argument.I have created a `variable` named `paramater` = `Hi` and send this as an request.But it is not concatinating it.

Can anyone tell me the way to pass values in restful API in node.js

Here's mine code

```
router.post('/restful', function (req, res) {
    var options = {
        uri: 'http://192.168.1.6:8080/sampleRest/RequestxARC/sample',
        method: 'post'

    };
    var parameters = "Hi";

    var responseFromClient = '';
    request(options, function (error, response, body, parameters) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            responseFromClient = body;
        }
        else {
            responseFromClient = 'Not Found';
        }
        console.log(responseFromClient);
        //res.json(resss);
        req.flash('response_msg', responseFromClient);

        if (responseFromClient != 'Not Found') {
            res.redirect('/users/restful');
        }
        else {
            res.redirect('/users/restful');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ` request(options, function (error, response, body)` request callback have only have 3 paramaters??

Comment: i guess you want to show `console.log(responseFromClient);` = Hi + body?

Comment: Yes..I have created  a method "sample"  in Rest/RequestxARC/sample where I am concatinating "Hi" from this route.js and then concating it with some other string value in the sample function and returning the string. But the problem which is coming is from routes this "Hi" is not getting passed.It is getting null

Comment: you can't add your variables on `request` callback function, what you can do is  make another variable `var responseNew` = parameters + ':' + body;

and do         console.log(responseNew);
        req.flash('response_msg', responseNew);

Comment: Now suppose I need to send some data attached and perform a corresponding action in rest api "sample" then how will I proceed?

Comment: `request.post('http://192.168.1.6:8080/sampleRest/RequestxARC/sample', {form:{key:'value'}}, callback)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If we want to use any value which is being passed from UI. We can use it by this way:
 router.post('/restful', function(req, res){
  var platformname=req.body.platform;//This is the way to attach variables from UI.
    var options = {
        uri : 'http://192.168.1.6:8080/sampleRest/RequestxARC/sample',
        body : platformname,
        method : 'post'

            }; 

    console.log(options.body +" value attached from UI");
    var responseFromClient = '';
    request(options,function (error, response, body ,form ,callback) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            responseFromClient = body;
        }
        else {
            responseFromClient = 'Not Found';
        }
        console.log(responseFromClient);

        //res.json(resss);
        req.flash('response_msg', responseFromClient);

        if(responseFromClient !='Not Found'){
          res.redirect('/users/restful');
        }
        else{
          res.redirect('/users/restful');
        }
    });
 });
```